# Is there a way to disable ability to change (horizontal) slider's value (e.g. volume) by scrolling mouse wheel (over it) in GNOME or KDE Plasma?

Tags: linux, mouse, scrolling

At first, it was a great feature, but after a while it started to bug me every time I want to scroll through a page of horizontal sliders (e.g. `pavucontrol`). And after several times of searching, I didn't find anything even close to my problem.

I would love to know if there's any method that can temporary or permanently disable this function. Maybe there's a flag somewhere in the hidden settings (e.g. `dconf-editor`).

Answer (score 0):

You can hold shift while scrolling.

Comment: If I hover over the slider and start scrolling with shift pressed - still changes slider's value. If just trying to scroll (over empty space) while holding shift - can't scroll at all (somehow shift prevents scrolling).